# Vue - How to show a dropdown from appbar on icon click?

Tags: vue.js, drop-down-menu, appbar

I have an appBar(mobile) with some icons on it. I want to show a dropdown when I click the notifications icon (as seen in many mobile apps) with the list of notifications. I am absolutely new to Vue.

```
            <template>
        <div>
            <!-- <v-app-bar color="deep-purple accent-4" dense dark> -->
            <v-menu>
            <template v-slot:activator="{ on: activationEvents }">
                <v-btn icon v-bind="attrs" v-on="activationEvents">
                <div class="notification" @click="showNotif" v-bind="attrs" v-on="on">
                    <fas class="notif-icon" :icon="['far', 'bell']" />
                    <span class="count" v-if="notification.unreadCount != 0">{{
                    notification.unreadCount.toLocaleString()
                    }}</span>
                </div>
                </v-btn>
            </template>

            <v-list>
                <v-list-item
                v-for="dessert in desserts"
                :key="dessert"
                @click="() => {}"
                >
                <v-list-item-title> {{ dessert.name }}</v-list-item-title>
                </v-list-item>
            </v-list>
            </v-menu>
            <!-- </v-app-bar> -->
        </div>
        </template>

            export default {
        data() {
            return {
            toggleSelect: false,
            desserts: [
                {
                name: "Frozen Yogurt",
                calories: 159,
                fat: 6.0,
                },
                {
                name: "Ice cream sandwich",
                calories: 237,
                fat: 9.0,
                },
                {
                name: "Eclair",
                calories: 262,
                fat: 16.0,
                },
                {
                name: "Cupcake",
                calories: 305,
                fat: 3.7,
                },
                {
                name: "Gingerbread",
                calories: 356,
                fat: 16.0,
                },
                {
                name: "Jelly bean",
                calories: 375,
                fat: 0.0,
                },
                {
                name: "Lollipop",
                calories: 392,
                fat: 0.2,
                },
                {
                name: "Honeycomb",
                calories: 408,
                fat: 3.2,
                },
                {
                name: "Donut",
                calories: 452,
                fat: 25.0,
                },
                {
                name: "KitKat",
                calories: 518,
                fat: 26.015,
                },
            ],
            notification: { unreadCount: 0 },
            };
        },
```

Currently, there are 2 problems:

The list gets displayed directly without even clicking on the icon

The list gets displayed on/in the appbar (instead of getting displayed below the appbar)

Comment: Have a look at [this example](https://codepen.io/pumax/pen/XvKEyP). You're probably looking for `<v-menu>`.

Comment: I have done pretty much the same thing already, except "new Vue..." I don't understand what that is. Also, what is Vuetify?

Comment: `new Vue({ ...stuff })` is the old syntax for `createApp({ ...stuff })`. Don't worry about it.

Answer (score 0):

Half an answer: The Menu prop `offset-y` will open the menu below. e.g.

```
<v-menu
    bottom
    left
  offset-y="offset-y"
>
```

Also the `nudge-bottom` property will allow you to move the menu down by a specific amount. e.g.

```
<v-menu
    bottom
    left
    nudge-bottom="40"
>
```

https://v2.vuetifyjs.com/en/api/v-menu/#props